minizing curves are smooth?
Let $M$ a Riemannian manifold with a metric $d(p,q)$. If we define a continuous curve $C$ to be admissible if it has bounded variation $ \sum_{i}d(C(t_i),C(t_{i-1}))\leq V$, in this case  there is well-defined length $l(C)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\sum_{i} d(C(t_i),C(t_{i-1}))$. Is it true that minimizing curves must be smooth geodesics?
It's clear minimizing curves in the family of piecewise smooth curves are geodesics, this can be proved via a variation argument. For the extended admissible family, it might be possible to use smooth curves to approximate the orinal curve, but this doesn't imply minimizing curve must be smooth.

Check Petersen's Riemannian Geometry, Theorem 5.3.3
